# Create an API downnload log file in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging

I have created log file using Winston package in my `node.js` appication.
I tried to create an API to download the log file, but I am not getting it what to pass in `res.download()`. If someone has already done it please support.

Comment: You are expected to pass an url.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this piece of code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/download',(req,res)=>{
    var url = "./sample.txt";
    res.download(url);
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer then please up vote to make it a valid answer.

Comment: I up voted already but its not reflecting, as I have less than 15 reputation